# Send custom error message in Ajax error in codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I am currently using Codeigniter and working on CRUD operation in one HTML form.
I am using Ajax for this create/read/update.

I have also used Transaction Management as best practices in a database query.

**The Problem:**

(1) I want separate Error message for Update and Insert Error. Which I did not get in the ajax error section.

(2) I have used the debugger to debug this problem but I do not get it proper.

Here is the Code of my controller.

**Controller**:

```
    public function save_candidate_experience() {
    $this->db->trans_start();

        if(empty($postId))){
            $query_staus = $this->test_model->insert_function( $data ); 

            if($query_staus != TRUE) {
                $msg = array('message'=>'Failed To Save! Erroe Wile Inserting.');
            } else{
                $msg = array('message'=>'Successfully Insert');
            }

        } else {
            $query_staus2 = $this->test_model->update_function( $data );    
            if($query_staus2 != TRUE) {
                $msg = array('message'=>'Failed To Save! Erroe Wile Updateing.');
            }else{
                $msg = array('message'=>'Successfully Updated');
            }
        }

       if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
         {
           $this->db->trans_rollback();
           echo json_encode ($msg);    
         }
      else
         {
           $this->db->trans_commit();
           echo json_encode ($msg);
         }
 }
```

**This is the Model Code**:

```
 public function insert_function() {

        $this->db->insert('table_name', $data);
            if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){
                return TRUE;
            } else{
                return FALSE;
            }

 }

 public function update_function() {

        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->update('test_table', $data);
            if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){
                return TRUE;
            } else{
                return FALSE;
            }

 }
```

**Ajax Code in my view**.

```
$.ajax({         
     type: 'POST',
     async: true,
     dataType: 'Json',         
     url: save_experience,
     data: $('#candidata_exp_form').serialize(),
     success: function (response) {
        //doing something with ajax success
     },error: function (msg)
     {
       alert(msg.message);
        // I know I can give alert message here but.
        //I don't want to give alert message here.
        //I want to indicate user that the error occure whilt insert or update seperately. 
     }
});
```

Comment: In ajax , you can check if you are sending `ID` for update. Then you can customize you error. Or you can add another index in `$msg`, and you can check for that in your ajax. Like `$msg['update'] = 1`, if you are updating, else `$msg['update'] = 0`. In ahax check what is the value for update.

Comment: That part is not the problem sir. I have managed it well, here for simplicity I have just put the just some of code only. the problem is just how to get which error came while process.

Comment: Can you be specific on `how to get which error came while process.`??

Comment: Sure Sir, I want to notify the user that the error occurs while updating or while inserting data. So I create different error message regarding the different operation. But in Ajax error, i did not get that proper that which error came up (insert error or update error). Is it clear sir or i can elaborate more.

Comment: your error message are clearly telling about operation. `Failed To Save! Erroe Wile Inserting` is for insert and `Failed To Save! Erroe Wile Updating` for update.

Comment: Yes sir, but I dit not get that in the Ajax.

Comment: Please check the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to understand 2 things.

Form validation error and ajax error is different.

Ajax error - Is not validation error.
It means, suppose you call a function and there is php error in that function, or 404 error. At that time `.error()` will be called.

Ajax Success - No error(No syntax error).

So now you should write the logic in ajax `success()`.

```
$.ajax({         
    type: 'POST',
    async: true,
    dataType: 'Json',         
    url: save_experience,
    data: $('#candidata_exp_form').serialize(),
    success: function (response) {
        alert(response.message);// this will alert you the message which you have put in `json_encode()`
    }
});
```

Comment: I think I am not able to describe my problem properly because What you suggest is what I did already.

Comment: Explain me with scenarios about your problem.

Comment: ok if I get an error in an update that I  did not get the id in where condition so an error occurs. I get $msg = " Failed To Save! Error While Updating. " The Problem is that when I alert in ajax error with like: alert(msg.message); it show undefined.

Comment: where have u written this line `alert(msg.message);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145843/discussion-between-niranjan-n-raju-and-ankit-suthar).

Comment: Why ? because it is an error and should be put in the error section. I get [object object] while alerting the msg in Ajax error section.